# p:remoteCommand only update="@all" PF5

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

On below code `<p:remoteCommand>` just update whole view when I use **@all**, but I've tried update `@this`,`@form` or `wizardEventContainer` without success. Even though `@all` work as I wish I would prefer just update the specific container `wizardEventContainer`

In the PrimeFaces website the example works using id attribute therefore I don't know why I can't get it too.

I work with PF5, JSF 2.2 and SWF 2.4. I changed JSF separator char to *-* instead of *:*

```
<h:form id="formEditor" styleClass="eventEditorForm" prependId="true">
            <p:editor id="editorEvent" height="150" width="900" maxlength="500" onchange="writeTextonPanel()" widgetVar="editorWidget"  />

            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="eventEditorButtons" styleClass="eventEditorButtons">
                <h:commandButton value="#{msg['saveLayer.btn']}" actionListener="#{eventProvider.saveTextLayer()}" alt="#{msg['saveLayer.btn.alt']}" title="#{msg['saveLayer.btn.title']}" onclick="showEditor('save')">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="-formBotones-wizardEventContainer" />
                </h:commandButton>
                <h:commandButton value="#{msg['omitLayer.btn']}" alt="#{msg['omitLayer.btn.alt']}" title="#{msg['omitLayer.btn.title']}" onclick="showEditor('delete')">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="-formBotones-wizardEventContainer" />
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:inputHidden id="tempCSS" value="#{eventProvider.tempCSS}" />
            <h:inputHidden id="tempHTML" value="#{eventProvider.tempHTML}" />
</h:form>

<h:form id="formBotones" prependId="true">

    <p:remoteCommand name="omitTextLayer" process="@this" update="formBotones-wizardEventContainer" actionListener="#{eventProvider.omitTextLayer()}" />
    <p:remoteCommand name="modifyTextLayer" actionListener="#{eventProvider.modifyTextLayer()}" />
    <h:inputHidden id="tempCSSforModify" value="#{eventProvider.tempCSSModified}" />

    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="wizardEventContainer" styleClass="wizardEventContainer">
        <h:inputHidden id="tempTextIdLayer" value="#{eventProvider.tempTextIdLayer}" />
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

**JS code linked with JAVA method**

```
function showEditor(mode){
if(mode=='save')
    saveLayer();

if(mode=='delete')
    deleteLayer();

if($('#eventEditorContainer').css('visibility')=="hidden"){
    $('#eventEditorContainer').css('visibility','visible');
    $('#formControl-textLayerBtn').prop("disabled",true);
}
else{
    $('#eventEditorContainer').css('visibility','hidden');
    $('#formControl-textLayerBtn').prop("disabled",false);
}

}

function deleteLayer(layer){


if(layer==null){
    var idLayer='formBotones-' + $('#formBotones-tempTextIdLayer').val();

    $('#' + idLayer).remove();

    $('#formEditor-tempCSS').val('');
    $('#formEditor-tempHTML').val('');

}
else{
    var idLayer=layer.parent().attr('id');


    layer.parent().remove();


    $('#formBotones-tempTextIdLayer').val(idLayer.substring(idLayer.indexOf("-")+1));
    $('#formEditor-tempCSS').val('');
    $('#formEditor-tempHTML').val('');


}

omitTextLayer(); // p:remoteCommand function

}
```

**P.D**: I'v edited adding full code sample and js code which link to java method on p:remoteCommand
Thanks!

Comment: The `process` attribute of `<p:remoteCommand>` is set to `@all` (default). Hence, it processes the whole view. Can you try with `process="@this"`? (though I think, it will not affect your concrete problem).

Comment: @Tiny I tried process="@this" update="@this" and no works. Is it possible there is any incompatibility with spring webflow? Because I got some problems with update property for several PF5 components and I changed my code for f:ajax behavior instead of PF5 update property.

Comment: `update` basically needs to set to some (container) components (depending upon your needs) such as `update="wizardEventContainer"` not just `update="@this"` which is `<p:remoteCommand>` itself. Shouldn't it? I have not yet worked with Spring WebFlow. Therefore, I am completely unaware of it. By observing the network monitor/browser console (to see, if there are some JavaScript errors), you should be able to get to the culprit, I hope. Finally, how do you associate those `<p:remoteCommand>`s with some components? In the current code snippet, no associations/attachments are seen. To be continued

Comment: You should essentially be doing something like this. Take a `<p:commandButton>`, for example - `<p:commandButton type="button" onclick="func()" value="Click".../>` and then you need to attach this button to `<p:remoteCommand name="func" update="wizardEventContainer".../>`. This remote command is attached to a button on the `onclick` JavaScript event (as an example). You could use an `action`/`actionListener` to invoke a bean method, if needed. I think, you should already be doing all of these. Do you? [Example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml).

Comment: @Tiny yep! Code was written as you say. I've added full code and JS for p:remoteCommand. Java function is thrown and I can debug it correctly. Now I've seen that wizardEventContainer is update from the commandButton on first form (formEditor) too. So, really I triy to update that container without success twice. As desesperate try I deleted f:ajaxBehavior and I set process="@this" update="wizardEventContainer" on p:remoteCommand but neither work.

Comment: Does it work, if you were to try on a blank playground project/application omitting that extra code `<p:editor>` and other noise which roughly has only one XHTML page with a basic XHTML structure and some code which is only meant for testing this phenomenon - just like `<h:commandButton onclick="omitTextLayer();".../>` and `<p:remoteCommand name="omitTextLayer".../>`?

Comment: I am not familiar with Spring WebFlow (which essentially should not have problems with) but Spring has no issue with this kind of things. Everything like this is working well in my application with several XHTML pages and Spring managed beans (Spring 4.0 GA, JSF 2.2.8-02, PrimeFaces 5.1 final (community release)).

Comment: You are right. It should work and in fact work on pf showcase website. I will create a project with spring, swf, pf and jsf2 and I will mimic that code on basic mode.  For me it's strange just work update="@all". Thanks for you time @Tiny. I'll post here the behavior for blank project.

Comment: You mentioned, "*I changed JSF separator char to `-` instead of `:`*". Can you just try it out by temporarily removing the associated `<context-param>` (`javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR`) from `web.xml` so that it could again default to `:`? You are using this character `-` at some places (`update="formBotones-wizardEventContainer"` in `<p:remoteCommand>`) You must guarantee that you do not use this character `-` yourself anywhere throughout your application to generate  JSF/PrimeFaces component IDs once you change `:` to `-`. JSF would otherwise be unable to locate `NamingContainer` components.

Comment: @Tiny resolved mystery! update works properly using IDs if remoteCommand is thrown from p:commandButton instead of h:commandButton. I don't know if this feature is so or it's a mistake. Change javax.faces.SEPARATOR_CHAR don't mind in this case. Thanks for all!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update works right using IDs if `p:remoteCommad` if thrown from `p:commandButton` instead of `h:commandButton`.

So, code must change to

```
<p:commandButton value="#{msg['omitLayer.btn']}" alt="#{msg['omitLayer.btn.alt']}" title="#{msg['omitLayer.btn.title']}" onclick="showEditor('delete')" />
```

Comment: Uh! First time seen :) (at least I never tried a `<p:remoteCommand>` with an `<h:commandButton>`) It is not easily guessable. Thank you for replying here.